# Why blacklisted tags `define` are showing up in auto complete?

Tags: support, tags, tag-blocklist

Today, I post one question and when I try add tag `define` to my question. The `define` tag is available to search.

[image]

However, when I add this tag to my question. Here is one mistake

[image]

The `define` tag is not allowed here, why this tag could be available?

Comment: What do you understand about the word "deprecated"?

Comment: Scratch that - you're asking why blacklisted tags are showing up in autocomplete, that's a reasonable concern. Not sure I'd tag this as a bug though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing in our system that determines a tag is blacklisted when suggesting it, because the blacklist is not attached to each tag, but is instead a list of regular expressions which match things when attempting to submit a post. While many of the blacklisted tags are regular expressions which only match one thing, it's not a requirement, and making it work with the suggestion system would mean running a bunch of regular expressions every single time someone typed something into that box.

Once all the questions still tagged with it have had the tag removed, the tag will disappear from the list and stop being suggested. Until then, it will continue appearing as any other tag because, well, it has questions with the tag. The same thing happens when a synonymized tag still has questions attached to it (pending a merge): it will show that tag in the list, even though it inevitably gets rewritten to the master tag upon submission.

For now, I've added an excerpt which will now show up when it appears in that list, so users won't expect it to actually work:

[image: Blacklisted Tag: Define]

Comment: "so users won't expect it to actually work" In theory ;)

Comment: Through it may be a bug that define appears first than other more popular tags, or it's selecting them by best match?

Comment: Why is the blacklist composed of regexes? Has the regex functionality been useful?

Comment: Why is it so hard to add a column to the tag table “DoNotSuggest” and then run a batch process to update it based on the black list reg expressions, synonymised tags etc?

Comment: @user2357112 I guess it's easier to classify classes of tags with regex, because otherwise people could just circumvent the tag blacklisting by using leetspeak etc. or using alternative writtings/shorter ones etc.